# Fatal error : Class PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter not found ( in PHING )

Tags: php, unit-testing, code-coverage, pear, phing

Pleaase help...

Inside my build.xml(under C:\xampp\php directory) is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

     <project name="my_project" default="code_coverage" basedir=".">

     <fileset dir="C:/xampp/htdocs/phpunittest/classes" id="php">
       <include name="*.php"/>
     </fileset>

    <fileset dir="C:/xampp/htdocs/phpunittest/tests" id="tests">
      <include name="Test*.php"/>
    </fileset>

    <target name="code_coverage">

      <mkdir dir="coverage_db"/>
      <mkdir dir="coverage_result"/>

      <coverage-setup database="coverage_db/coverage.db">
        <fileset refid="php"/>
      </coverage-setup>

      <phpunit2 codecoverage="true" haltonerror="true">
        <batchtest>
          <fileset refid="tests"/>
        </batchtest>
      </phpunit2>

     <coverage-report outfile="coverage_db/coverage.xml">
        <report todir="coverage_result"/>
      </coverage-report>

      </target>
 </project>
```

In the command prompt :

I go to the php directory and typed

```
 phing
```

the build.xml is executed but in runtime i got a

> fatal error "Class PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter not found in    C:\xampp\php\PEAR\phing\tasks\ext\coverage\CoverageSetupTask.php on line 169"

I just installed the latest version of phpunit and phing by following this tutorial http://devzone.zend.com/article/2955 (please have a look) and cant figure out why im getting that error...

Im using Windows XP and Apache Server (XAMPP)

Is this a bug?
If not, what could be the solution for this?

Please hellpp... i really2x need help

Any suggestions would be a great help for me

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have the `PHP_CodeCoverage` package installed from the phpunit channel because you forced the installation of phpunit without knowing what you did.

Fix it by installing it:

```
$ pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage
```

Comment: Hi cweiske, I followed what  u said but it gives me a message "No releases available for package 'pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage'"..

Any suggestions? thx

Comment: I uninstall xampp and install wampp... i still got that error... and now when i tried "pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage" , i got the mssage "php/PHPUnit is already installed and is the same as the release version 1.0.5"

Comment: Did you install phing via pear?

Comment: ohww.. sorry i solve it using pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage